# Ambiguous reference between MonoGame & Microsoft.XNA.Framework namespaces

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-8, monogame

MonoGame (a framework which basically brings XNA to Windows Phone 8) has all it's namespaces prefixed with `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` I believe to minimise the amount of code changes required when porting your XNA app to MonoGame.

My issue is, I wish to access the `Microphone` class, which, because has not been created in MonoGame yet, I have to utilize it from within in the official Microsoft XNA class, this requires taking out the explicit forced removal of the standard `Microsoft.XNA.Framework.dll` references within the .csproj that my MonoGame template has setup to avoid conflicts, which works great and now `Microphone` is accessible, but in doing so I have created ambiguity between a few key classes which both exist in Microsoft standard issue and MonoGame.

The errors I am receiving are:

> Ambiguous reference: 
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color

This has obviously occurred because alongside the standard Microsoft-issued XNA library, I have a reference to `MonoGame.Framework.dll` which commandeers the namespace, creating this ambiguity. However, in all instances, I wish to access the MonoGame version.

Any ideas how I can explicitly tell the compiler to use the MonoGame version of the `Color` and `Vector2` class and not the official Microsoft one?

Any attempt in a `using Color = Microsoft.Xna.Framework` obviously won't work because they are both labelled the same in the compiled dlls!

Comment: If the namespaces are identical then it seems you will have to recompile MonoGame to use a different namespace. The only other alternative is to create a wrapper for the few methods you do want to use. Be sure you are explicit in which reference you actually want to use in this new class.  I also would caution you with regards to using XNA since Microsoft has basically discontinued its development.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider a wrapper.. just hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: You want to use both references and they both share the exact same namespace the problem is with MonoGame there isn't an elegant solution.  Of course I seriously doubt the full namespace is `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color` you would have to look to the code to determine what it actually is.

Comment: @Ramhound Uh... There's a much better solution - see my answer. Also XNA/MonoGame is a reasonable technology choice. And `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color` really *is* the full namespace and class name for `Color`.

Comment: @AndrewRussell - If the full namespace is an exactly the same then that is a poor design choice on the part of MonoGamee.  While its a reasonable choice today because XBOX 360 and Windows 8 currently supports it, going forward in the very near future, it might not be a reasonable solution.  I only brought it up because it needed to be said.

Comment: Re MonoGame: It's a deliberate and sound choice. It's designed to be source-code compatible with XNA. You take your XNA source, switch out the assembly references, and it should "just work". (Of course, until they actually *finish* it - `Microphone` and all - it doesn't always work like that.) Conditionally changing `using` statements is a nightmare - that's what you had to do in the very early days, and they changed it. (Re XNA: Maybe true, but MonoGame+XNA is a different choice to "just" XNA.)

Comment: Funny to stir up some debate \*grabs some popcorn\* Thanks all for your answers, I'd love to contribute and add `Microphone` but I wouldn't really know where to start especially talking interfacing to a WP8 microphone component, or if it's a matter of just simply porting the same code from XNA decompiled into the MonoGame sources..

Comment: @GONeale You can't "copy" the copyright code from XNA ;)

Comment: Ok, well there we have it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to solve this specific problem is by using an `extern alias` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx), [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/28/extern-alias-walkthrough.aspx)).

That way you can alias the Microsoft XNA DLL and specify an appropriate `using` statement just for the `Microphone` class. Continue using MonoGame as normal.

Possibly a better solution might be to make your own wrapper class called `Microphone` in the namespace `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio` using this technique. Put it in a separate assembly so you don't have to pollute your main source code with the `extern alias` stuff.

The ideal way, of course, is to actually implement `Microphone` for MonoGame and contribute it ;)

(Of course, this answer says nothing about how successful you might be at mixing MonoGame and XNA in this way, functionality-wise. Hopefully it works.)

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for your answer and greetings from the G/C :) Only about an hour from you.... ;) Will give the `extern alias` a go when I return home, thanks.

Comment: Ahh.. you were the author of "Dark" sweet :) I thought your name sounded familiar...

Comment: Excellent! I found the extern alias the best way to go, I now have the following declared, while verbose, I much prefer than upkeeping a wrapper library: `MonoGameFramework::Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
MonoGameFramework::Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
private MonoGameFramework::Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont spriteFont;
private Microphone mic = Microphone.Default;`

This has allowed me to utilise both the standard Microsoft.XNA.Framework classes provided by WP8 and the MonoGame ones, thanks again for the suggestion!