# Instance Argument: Cannot convert an object to its own type

Tags: c#, build, xna, visual-studio-2013, monogame

I am creating a **MonoGame** Project via the **NuGet** packages. I started with a blank project and ran "Install-Package MonoGame" in the Package Manager Console. Afterwards I copied all my old code, changed the namespace to the new project name, and since then I am having strange build issues with **Visual Studio**, that don't go away after restarting VS or Rebuilding the Solution.

All of them have to do with `Vector2` objects. I have had to create an extension method to access Vector2.X because VS could not find a definition for X within `Vector2`, even though if I hit F12 it takes me straight to Vector2.X. I've had to create a static method to create Vector2 instances because "new Vector2(x, y)" is an invalid argument for a method that needs `Vector2` objects as parameters. Lastly, I have this line of code:

```
PhysicsBody.Position = Extras.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(value.X, value.Y));
```

And for it I get the error "Instance Argument: cannot convert from '`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2`' to '`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2`'". How is this even possible? I know I can continue adding static methods to do simple things that for some reason cause build errors until all the Vector2 stupidity is gone, but is there a fix that will make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoGame is most likely referencing a different version of XNA, or has used the same namespace for an alternate implementation to minimize code impact to end developers.

See @ayls answer to this similar question [Monogame Ambiguous Vector2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676064/monogame-ambiguous-vector2) for an approach.

Actually, this answer from @Andrew Russell looks even more authoritative [Ambiguous reference between MonoGame & Microsoft.XNA.Framework namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225017/ambiguous-reference-between-monogame-microsoft-xna-framework-namespaces)

Comment: I am now getting the error "Thy type `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a freference to assembly `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah". I have tried using Monogame's beta installer (that they make really hard to find), and after restarting the process of creating a project (this time using MonoGame templates), copying code files (but not settings), and trying to build, I get the same exact problems with Vector2. What I don't understand is that it's complaining about Vector3 now.